# Lambda based matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I am calling matrix implemented with a lambda "lambda matrix". The full working program:

```
   // g++ prog.cc -std=c++17
   // gcc 8.2.0

     #include <iostream>
     #include <cassert>
     #include <memory>

    [[noreturn]] inline void terror
    (char const * msg_, char const * file_, const unsigned line_)
    {
        assert(msg_ != nullptr);    assert(file_ != nullptr);   assert(line_ > 0);
        ::fprintf(stderr, "\n\nTerminating ERROR:%s\n%s (%d)", msg_, file_, line_);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

      #define DBJ_VERIFY_(x, file, line ) if (false == (x) ) terror( #x ", failed", file, line )
      #define DBJ_VERIFY(x) DBJ_VERIFY_(x,__FILE__,__LINE__)

inline auto print = []( auto const & first_param, auto const & ... params)
{
    std::cout << first_param ;
    // if there are  more params
    if constexpr (sizeof...(params) > 0) {
        // recurse
        print(params...);
    }
    return print;
};

 namespace dbj::mtx
{
    constexpr unsigned short max_cols = 0xFFFF;
    constexpr unsigned short max_rows = 0xFFFF;

    template<typename T>
    auto mtx(unsigned short height_, unsigned short width_)
    {
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v <T>, "\n\nstatic assert in:\n\n" __FUNCSIG__ "\n\n\tOnly numbers please!\n\n");
    #else
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v <T>, "\n\nstatic assert in: dbj::mtx::mtx()\t\nOnly numbers please!\n\n");
    #endif
        DBJ_VERIFY(width_ <= max_cols);
        DBJ_VERIFY(height_ <= max_rows);

        return [
            arry = std::make_unique<T[]>(height_ * width_), height_, width_
        ]
        (size_t row_, size_t col_) mutable->T&
        {
                DBJ_VERIFY(row_ <= height_);
                DBJ_VERIFY(col_ <= width_ );
            // arry is moved into here
            return arry[row_ * width_ + col_];
        };
    }
    /*
    visitor signature

    bool (*) (unsigned short rows_, unsigned short columns_,
        auto & mtx_, auto const & visitor_);        

        processing stops on false returned
    */
    auto for_each_cell = []
    (unsigned short rows_, unsigned short columns_,
        auto & mtx_, auto const & visitor_
    )
    {
        assert(columns_ <= max_cols);
        assert(rows_ <= max_rows);

        for (auto j = 0; j < rows_; j++)
            for (auto k = 0; k < columns_; k++)
            {
                if (false == visitor_(mtx_(j, k), j, k)) return;
            }
    };
} // mtx

int main()
{
    using namespace dbj::mtx;
    auto R = 3, C = 3;

    auto mx_1 = mtx<int>(R, C);
    auto mx_2 = mtx<int>(R, C);
    auto mx_3 = mtx<int>(R, C);

    // population
    auto put42 = [](auto & val_, auto row, auto cel) -> bool
    {
        val_ = 42;  return true;
    };
    for_each_cell(R, C, mx_1, put42) ;
    for_each_cell(R, C, mx_2, put42) ;

    // addition
    auto adder_visitor = [&](auto & val_, auto row, auto cel) -> bool
    {
        mx_3(row, cel) = mx_1(row, cel) + mx_2(row, cel);
        return true;
    };

    for_each_cell(R, C, mx_3, adder_visitor);

    // display
        auto printer_visitor = [R,C](auto & val_, short row, short col) 
        {
            static int col_counter_ = 1;
            if ((0 == row)  && (0 == col) ) print("\ndbj::mtx {");
            if (0 == (col % C ))    print("\n\t{");
                // full display: print(" [", row,",",col,"] = ",val_, " ");
                print(" ",val_, " ");
            if ( 0 == ( col_counter_ % C)) print("}");
            if ((R == row+1) && (C == col+1))   print("\n}\n");
            col_counter_++;
            return true;
        };

    print("\nMX 1");
    for_each_cell(R, C, mx_1, printer_visitor);

    print("\nMX 2");
    for_each_cell(R, C, mx_2, printer_visitor);

    print("\nMX 3");
    for_each_cell(R, C, mx_3, printer_visitor);
}
```

What I like about this approach is simplicity. I also allocate once on the heap in one contigous mem block.  So far so good.

Works etc. Obvously one has to "believe in lambdas" to like this. Not a lot, but I do like it.

Also, I would like to measure the perfomance but against what? Some "class-based" classical Matrix?

Also are there some difficult edge-cases or singularities you can spot? I am also slightly puzzled when is that shared pointer going to delete the array it holds.

Please let me know what do you think.

### Update

Added the "fast" version, Compile time, pod stack matrix based.

```
       // the compile time solution
   template<typename T, size_t H, size_t W>
   inline auto fast_mtx () {
        static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v <T>);
        static_assert(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v <T>);

           constexpr auto height_ = H ;
           constexpr auto width_  = W ;

        static_assert(width_ <= max_cols);
        static_assert(height_ <= max_rows);           

       T arry[H*W]{};

        return [
            arry , height_, width_
        ]
        (size_t row_, size_t col_) mutable->T&
        {
          if constexpr(check_indexes_on_each_call) {
                DBJ_VERIFY(row_ <= height_);
                DBJ_VERIFY(col_ <= width_ );
          }
            // arry is moved into here
            return arry[row_ * width_ + col_];
        };
   } // fast_mtx
```

Full working program is also [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hSE7d24YmNIOSVII). It is becoming too long to copy paste it here, and too tedious too do it on each change.

Comment: @TobySpeight Full working program is here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1vKwAw2e1gnLoRrX

Comment: Please [Do not add an improved version of the code after receiving an answer](/help/someone-answers) - the "update" code is probably best posted as a new question, referencing this one for context.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add a few headers to get this to compile:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
```

There's also use of an undefined identifier `__FUNCSIG__` that I needed to remove.

---

`std::size_t` is misspelt throughout (implementations are *allowed*, but not *required* to declare `::size_t` in addition to `std::size_t`; portable code shouldn't assume so).

---

Why do we have such small limits on the number of rows and columns?  We ought to allow any size we can allocate (i.e. any combination whose product fits in a `std::size_t`).  Note that `assert()` is the wrong way to check public arguments - remember that it's compiled out when `NDEBUG` is defined.

At the other end of the scale, should a matrix with zero elements be allowed?  I don't see why not (and the zero-sized allocation is perfectly legal), but just to make sure you've considered it...

---

We could move the pointer into the lambda, so we don't need to increase its reference count:

```
    return [arry = std::move(arry), rows_, columns_](size_t row_, size_t col_) 
        -> T&
    {
        return arry[row_ * columns_ + col_];
    };
```

That allows us to use a unique pointer instead:

```
    auto arry = std::make_unique<T[]>(rows_ * columns_);
```

And combine the two:

```
    return [arry = std::make_unique<T[]>(rows_ * columns_), rows_, columns_]
           (size_t row_, size_t col_) -> T&
    {
        // arry is moved into here
        return arry[row_ * columns_ + col_];
    };
```

The lifetime is correct - the capture is destructed when the lambda is (and Valgrind confirms that, if there was any doubt).

---

Having suggested improvements to the use of the smart pointer, it's not what I'd prefer: instead of using a pointer to an array, it's clearer to allocate a `std::vector`.  If we don't resize it, it's exactly equivalent to the shared pointer.  Like this:

```
    return [arry = std::vector<T>(rows_ * columns_), rows_, columns_]
           (size_t row_, size_t col_) mutable -> T&
    {
        // arry is moved into here
        return arry[row_ * columns_ + col_];
    };
```

---

Minor: `false == foo` is normally written `!foo`.

Comment: The code in the lambda declaration area ... I have not seen this elsewhere. Interesting.

Comment: Allowed size was completely arbitrary, increased to 0xFFFF per matrix side.

Comment: In some other code (last week) I found std::vector<T> to be measurably slower vs std::unique_ptr<T[]> ...

Comment: The performance comparison is surprising; I'd be interested to see how you benchmarked.  The syntax for lambda capture with initializer was introduced with C++14.